# Are we sure Millenium Prize Problems can be solved?

Tags: logic, incompleteness, decidability

I would like to know if we are sure that the 6 remaining Millenium Prize Problems, like the Riemann hypothesis and the P vs NP problem, have a proof in set theory. They might fall into the undecidable category as far as we know, right?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: They may be insoluble, but if we could prove that, that would be just as good.

Comment: The specific case of RH is handled in this [MathOverflow post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/79685/can-the-riemann-hypothesis-be-undecidable). tl;dr if it *is* false, then we can prove it; if not, we have no idea.

Comment: As an example, the first of Hilbert's list of problems, known as the Continuum Hypothesis, has famously been proved unsolvable within set theory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No we are not sure. So what?

“Problems worthy of attack 
prove their worth by fighting back.”

― Piet Hein, Grooks 1

Comment: I love that quote!

Comment: So... We might spend a lot of time on researches that lead to nothing, but thank you, I've got my answer.